# Building a list of lists from a string

Tags: python, string, list

Given a specific string, my function needs to create a list of lists using all of the characters from that string. The function should start a new list whenever it sees `\n` in the string.

Example: `build_lst("\n....\n.B.d\n")` should return this list of lists: `[['.','.','.','.'],['.','B','.','d']]` because those 8 characters were present in the string. It creates the list of lists in the order that the characters appear in the string and as I mentioned `\n` divides the multiple individual lists within the main list.

My code so far is short but I think this could be accomplished with just a couple lines of code. Not sure if I am on the right track or if another strategy is better

Code:

```
def build_lst(s):

my_lst = s.split('\n')
[map(int) for x in my_lst]
```

Comment: Try `[list(x) for x in "\n....\n.B.d\n".strip().split("\n")]`.

Comment: why `map(int)`? how does that relate to your expected output?

Comment: @njzk2 I'm not exactly sure I was doing some research on how to do this before asking the question and that seemed to be how it was done. I realize now that I don't need to convert to Int. Juanpa.arrivillaga's solution worked perfectly going to select his answer as best answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe all you want is:

```
>>> s = "\n....\n.B.d\n" 
>>> list(map(list,s.strip().split('\n')))
[['.', '.', '.', '.'], ['.', 'B', '.', 'd']]
```

In Python 2, you can leave out the outer call to `list` and leave it at the `map` since `map` is evaluated eagerly instead of lazily as in Python 3.

Comment: Thank you your solution worked perfectly. I set new_lst equal to your solution 'list(map(list,s.strip().split('\n')))' and then instructed python to return new_lst and it functions correctly

Answer (score 0):

A [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) is a nice, maintainable way to go:

```
[ list(line) for line in s.split('\n') ]
```

If blank input lines should be omitted when constructing the output, add a conditional to the list comprehension:

```
[ list(line) for line in s.split('\n') if line ]
```

...and if leading and trailing whitespace should be ignored:

```
[ list(line.strip()) for line in s.split('\n') if line.strip() ]
```

Comment: how can there be `\n` if you are splitting on `\n`?

Comment: hah! Yes, that was force-of-habit from iterating over lines read from a text file.  Edited.